# cross referencing tables and inserting the results into another table SQL

Tags: php, sql

So i have 3 tables that are like the following:

table 1 - cats - that has the following structure:

```
  id   name       plural_name 
   0   painters   painters
   1   builders   builders
```

table 2 - places - that has the following structure

```
       place_id   place_name       classification
       243        painter comp     painters
       230        builder comp     builders
```

table 3 - rel_place_cat - that has the following structure

```
      id    place_id    cat_id 

        0   243         0
        1   230         1
```

So basically i need to run an SQL command to find to find the category id number in table 1 and the place_id from table 2 and insert the data into table 3

can this be done ?

Thank you

Comment: If you add `cat_id` in `table 2`, you will not need the 3rd table.

Comment: problem is i am using and modifying an existing php platform that cross references data table to speed up the system, there are over 2.5 million recored in places and over 1500 categories in the cats table

Comment: Ok, so we can have a join on `name` and `classification` assuming both are having same domain of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make that insert also repeatable?
Then you could also join to the relation table.
And only insert the missing relations.

**Example query:**

```
INSERT INTO rel_place_cat (place_id, cat_id) 
SELECT p.place_id, c.id 
FROM cats c 
JOIN places p ON p.classification = c.plural_name
LEFT JOIN rel_place_cat r ON (r.place_id = p.place_id AND r.cat_id = c.id)
WHERE r.id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.place_id, c.id;
```

Not sure if joining the "classification" to "plural_name" or to "name" would be better.
In the sample they are the same anyway.
But those values in "classification" are all plural, so "plural_name" was used for the join.

Comment: That's good. And thanks for the rep.  I guess that mod was just for the real table names?  Or did you choose the link to "name" instead? (just curious)

Comment: yes it was just change it to name, also converted into a php query so that i could make use of not overloading the phpmyadmin (sorry working on budget server with lots of limits) thank you once again, a greta fix and a great learning curve

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

`insert into table3(place_id, cat_id) 
 select place_id, cat_id 
from(select place_id, cat_id 
 from table1 
 inner join table2 on table1.name = table 2.classification)`

Should work.

Comment: this looks like the right way but i am not sure from(select place_id, cat_id 
 from table1 
 inner join table2 on table1.name = table 2.classification) is correct

Comment: Do the name and classification not hold the same data?

Comment: yes the name on table 1 is the same as classification on table 2, so i may have 200,000 builder with the same cat id etc

Comment: you can do a group by to get the distinct classification values. You can make play around with the select statement between the brackets separately till you get only distinct "name" values